# Spring State machine general usage

Tags: spring-statemachine

can someone please clarify for me, when im Autowiring Spring State Machine, and execute start() method, am i creating the instance of the state machine, similarly to lets say Activiti ProcessInstance or Camunda ProcessInstance.

Answer (score 0):

If you let spring context to create a single machine you create one instance within a jvm, start/stop really doesn't matter. In a same way if you create a machine factory, you can ask that factory to create individual instances in a same jvm. Don't know activity/camunda so don't know how those relates to processes.